# How to display validation rule error message for opportunity multi line layout?

Tags: opportunity, validation-rule, opportunity-lineitem

I am have requirement to display error message while adding opportunity products in multi line layout. i have created validation rule with respect to condition on custom fields which are  added to Opportunity Product Object, but i am not able display error message at top of page. It is displaying in seperate column as show in image[image]

Thanks in advance. Why are not able to display error message on top of the page in opportunity multi line layout?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't display the error message on top of the page of a multi-line layout because of unlike the single record page layout, multi-line layout may contain multiple records there may have multiple error messages layout for the different record.

But if you choose Error Location  'Top of Page' in the VR
[image]

you can show the  display the error message respect to the record or followed by the record, see the screen short 
[image]